# Oracle sql: insert into by copying from two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, sql-insert, insert-into

Although it's much more complex than I'm about to explain, I'll try to only stick to the relevant bits of what I want to accomplish. Our data model is quite complex, and the terms are also a bit confusing. We basically have a `Request`, and this request can have an active `Request_Status` (which has an `Enum_Value` to indicate it's current status), as well as previous `Request_Statuses` that aren't relevant anymore (to preserve history). A Person is linked to this `Request`, but the `Values` that are entered are linked to the current `Request_Status`.

So here are those tables, and the relevant columns:

#### `Persons`:

- `person_id`
- `unique_code`
- Some other values

#### `Requests`:

- `request_id`
- `fk_person_id`
- `year`
- Some other values

#### `Enum_Values`:

- `enum_value_id`
- `value`
- Some other values

#### `Request_Statuses`:

- `request_status_id`
- `fk_request_id`
- `fk_enum_value_id`
- `created_date`
- Some other values

#### `Values`:

- `value_id`
- `fk_request_status_id`
- Some other values

---

**I have:** A list of `Person.unique_codes`.
**I want to achieve two things:**

1. For each `Person.unique_code` I want to get the `Request` of the `year` 2017, and then create a new `Request_Status` with `fk_enum_value_id` set to 4, linked to this existing `Request`.
2. Create copies of the `Values` that were linked to the previously active `Request_Status`, and set their `fk_request_status_id` to the currently active `Request_Status` (the records I've created in step 1).

I've been able to do step 1 myself with a monstrous query (but it works..)
Here is the monstrous query for step 1:

Some things to note:
- There will only be a single `Request` of a given `year`.
- There can be more than one `Request_Statuses` for a given `Request`, so finding the active is the one with the highest `created_date`.
- `p.unique_code IN ('12345','67890')` is privatized and reduced code. In reality I have about 500 `person.unique_codes`.
- `SELECT rs1.fk_request_id, 4 /*, some other irrelevant values */ FROM Request_Statuses rs1 LEFT JOIN Request_Statuses rs2 ON (rs1.fk_request_id = rs2.fk_request_id AND rs1.created_date < rs2.created_date) WHERE rs2.created_date IS NULL` is copied from [this SO answer for the question "*Retrieving the last record in each group*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/1682559). I've used the windowing function at the top before, but it wasn't really suitable for sub-queries in combination with Oracle SQL, so I've used the (probably slightly slower) original method that was posted in 2009, which does work as intended.

```
INSERT_INTO Request_Statuses (fk_request_id, fk_enum_value_id /*, some other irrelevant values */)
(SELECT rs1.fk_request_id, 4 /*, some other irrelevant values */ FROM Request_Statuses rs1
LEFT JOIN Request_Statuses rs2 ON (rs1.fk_request_id = rs2.fk_request_id AND rs1.created_date < rs2.created_date)
WHERE rs2.created_date IS NULL AND rs1.fk_request_id IN (SELECT r.request_id FROM Requests r
WHERE r.fk_person_id IN (SELECT p.person_id FROM Persons p
WHERE p.unique_code IN ('12345','67890')) AND r.year = 2017));
```

And I'm currently working on step 2.
I currently have this:

```
INSERT INTO Values (fk_request_status_id /* some other irrelevant values */)
(SELECT /*TODO: Get request_status_id created in step 1*/, /* some other irrelevant values */
FROM Values v1 WHERE v1.fk_request_status_id IN (SELECT rs.status_id FROM Request_Statuses rs
WHERE rs.fk_request_id IN (SELECT r.request_id FROM Requests r
WHERE r.fk_person_id IN (SELECT p.person_id FROM Persons p
WHERE p.bsn IN ('12345','67890')) AND r.year = 2017) AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Values v2
WHERE v2.fk_request_status_id = rs.status_id) > 0));
```

All I need is to get the `request_status_id` of the `Request_Statuses` I've created in step 1, based on the same `person.unique_code`, and insert it at the `TODO`..

I've also been thinking about using a default value for now, and then update just the `fk_request_status_id` with a third (monstrous) query. Unfortunately, the `fk_request_status_id` in combination with a second column in the `Values` table form an unique constraint, and `fk_request_status_id` cannot be empty, so I can't just insert any value here to update later.. Maybe I should remove the constraints temporarily, and add them later again after the query..

PS: Performance isn't that important. I've only got around 500-750 `person.unique_codes` for which I have to create one new `Request_Status` each (and zero to about 50 `Values` that are potentially linked to the previous active `Request_Status`). It should work in under 4 hours, though. ;)

Comment: Maybe the simplest option is to CTAS VALUES_TEMP table, fill it with desired data (no matter how *monstruous* code you use), and then copy it back to VALUES.

Comment: @Littlefoot Hmm, that might not be a bad idea. Just a `TEMP_Values` table that is an exact copy of `Values`, but without the constraints, and then just use two separated queries. I'll probably do that for now, unless someone comes up with a better approach. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Exactly; without constraints, you can write any code you want - UPDATE back and forth until you're satisfied with the result. Though, the final result should really be OK, otherwise INSERT INTO VALUES will fail (which is OK; it would be bad if invalid values came into VALUES table).

Comment: It would be much easier for us to grasp your requirements if you could update your question to include sample data for each of your tables (we only need data for the required columns, and it can be test data), along with the output you're looking to obtain. That way, we can play around with the data ourselves.

Comment: @Boneist I'm currently at home, but I will do that on Monday. Thanks for the suggestion.